# How do I convert a Ruby hash to XML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, hash

Here is the specific XML I ultimately need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
  <email>joe@example.com</email>
  <first_name>Joe</first_name>
  <last_name>Blow</last_name>
</customer>
```

But say I have a controller ([Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails)) that is sending the data to a method. I'd prefer to send it as a hash, like so:

```
:first_name => 'Joe',
:last_name => 'Blow',
:email => 'joe@example.com'
```

So, how can I convert the hash to that XML format?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

ActiveSupport adds a `to_xml` method to Hash, so you can get pretty close to what you are looking for with this:

```
sudo gem install activesupport
```

```
require "active_support/core_ext"

my_hash = { :first_name => 'Joe', :last_name => 'Blow', :email => 'joe@example.com'}
my_hash.to_xml(:root => 'customer')
```

And end up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>  
   <last-name>Blow</last-name>  
   <first-name>Joe</first-name>  
   <email>joe@example.com</email>
</customer>
```

Note that the underscores are converted to dashes.

Comment: Ah nice, the root option was what was throwing me off. Thanks!

Comment: How does one add attributes to an XML element using this method?

Comment: you'll need: `sudo gem install activesupport` and in the code `require "active_support/core_ext"` to have `Hash#to_xml`

Comment: As of Rails 3.0, to_xml is no longer in ActiveSupport, but is instead added as a method on Ruby's Hash and Array classes.

Answer (score 6):

Gem [gyoku](https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku) very nice.

```
Gyoku.xml(:lower_camel_case => "key")    
# => "<lowerCamelCase>key</lowerCamelCase>"

Gyoku.xml({ :camel_case => "key" }, { :key_converter => :camelcase })
# => "<CamelCase>key</CamelCase>"

Gyoku.xml({ acronym_abc: "value" }, key_converter: lambda { |key| key.camelize(:lower) })
# => "<acronymABC>value</acronymABC>"
```

and more useful options.

Comment: Great post, do you know of any Gem that convert to JSON??

Answer (score 3):

If this data is a model, look at overriding `to_xml`.

Otherwise, [Builder](http://builder.rubyforge.org/) is a good option.

Comment: Well, I've tried to_xml and it's adding a <hash> tag around my XML. ie. 

  <hash>
  <customer>
  ...
  </customer>
  </hash>

Comment: Is your customer hash an active record object?

Comment: Check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001876 for info on overriding how you want your XML structured.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a gem like [XmlSimple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/) which provides this kind of facility.

Comment: This worked for me as I am not using Rails. Here's a one-liner for hash to xml:

`XmlSimple.xml_out(hash, {:keeproot => true, :noescape => true})`

Answer (score 2):

I did a short presentation about exactly that topic at my university a while back.   [Here](http://blog.marc-seeger.de/2008/11/25/ruby-xml-mapping/) are the slides (Interesting part starts at >= page 37)