# How to convert params to a xml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have this params:

```
Parameters:

 {"metodo"=>"cartao-credito",
 "formaPagamento"=>{"cartao"=>{"parcelas"=>"1"}},
 "tokenPagamento"=>"21162f8f1c2204a0c83fe9710437d5e1276f59fc"}
```

I need to convert them into a xml like this:

```
<integracao>
<formaPagamento>
   <metodo>cartao-credito</metodo>
    <cartao>   
       <parcelas>2</parcelas>
    </cartao>
</formaPagamento>
<tokenPagamento>21162f8f1c2204a0c83fe9710437d5e1276f59fc</tokenPagamento>
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a ruby hash to XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739905/how-do-i-convert-a-ruby-hash-to-xml)